# Angular not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and want to start practicing some code.  I created a simple app but the angular expression is not evaluating in the browser. My

## {{inventory.product.name}}

prints to the browser as {{inventory.product.name}}; however, if I go to view page source my angular.min file is loaded.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, thanks.

HTML CODE

```
  <title>Angular Practice</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-app="inventory">

  <div ng-controller="InventoryController as inventory">
  <h1>{{inventory.product.name}}</h1>
  <h2>Product Amount</h2>
  <p>Product description</p>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

ANGULAR CODE

```
  (Function(){
      var app = angular.module('inventory', []);

      app.controller('InventoryController', function(){
         this.product = item;
      });

      var item = {
      name: 'Test Item',
      amount: 10,
      description: 'This is the first test item',
      }
  })();
```

Comment: what errors are thrown in browser dev tools console? That is always the first place to check

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=inventory&p1=Error%…%20Bc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fangular%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A179)
    at angular.min.js:6
    at angular.min.js:40
    at q (angular.min.js:7)
    at g (angular.min.js:39)
    at cb (angular.min.js:43)
    at c (angular.min.js:20)
    at Bc (angular.min.js:21)
    at fe (angular.min.js:20)
    at angular.min.js:317
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:189)

Comment: `Function` should be `function` ...javascript is case sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JS code, `Function()` should be `function()`. Note that Javascript is case sensitive.

**Working code snippet:**

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('inventory', []);

  app.controller('InventoryController', function() {
    this.product = item;
  });

  var item = {
    name: 'Test Item',
    amount: 10,
    description: 'This is the first test item',
  }
})();
```

```html
<body ng-app="inventory">

  <div ng-controller="InventoryController as inventory">
    <h1>{{inventory.product.name}}</h1>
    <h2>Product Amount</h2>
    <p>Product description</p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
```